# Finding angle on an inclined plane

Tags: geometry, physics, triangles

How can I go about finding the angle, theta, in this Physics problem?

[image]

As you can tell, the right-most triangle is a simple 30-60-90 triangle, so above the right angle is a 60deg angle. Then the vertical angle theorem proves the vertical angle to be 60deg as well. I am stuck at this point. How can I find theta?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think we can get $\theta$. No more information?

Comment: That's what I though. Unless the triangle with theta is right, I can't figure it out. This was all the information.

Comment: Without the assumption that the "angled" line is normal to the slant, you cannot solve the problem.  But, any physics problem like this will assume that is the case.  (Of course, the diagram is horrible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that the line that goes through the center of the box on the ramp is perpendicular to the surface of the ramp (which is often the case when you consider normal force and want to resolve the weight force vector into two components), then we get that $\theta = 30^\circ$.

Comment: Though it appears like the triangle with angle theta is a right triangle from the picture. I can say for sure it does not look like a right triangle on the paper itself. Is there no other way but assumptions for this?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It might help to consider the context of the problem; are they asking you to draw a free body diagram?

Comment: The question is: "How large is angle theta?" In a later question the line coming off the triangle that makes a right angle is made a vector with a magnitude of 20 units and it asks to find the length of its component vectors.

Comment: I suppose it must be so. Thanks for your help!